# Problem connecting laptop (Ubuntu 14.04) to WiFi network

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

Okay, so I recently downloaded Ubuntu and installed it to run alongside Windows 7. When I started Ubuntu, I could not find my WiFi network in the network list. My ISP (Internet Service Provider) is Iburst (now Vox Telecom). It's been maybe two months now and I still can't find my WiFi network. My PC is rather new, and I later installed the exact same Ubuntu onto another, older laptop. It works just fine and it can find my WiFi network... What could be wrong?

My output when I run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

```
05:00:0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:0510]
Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
```

I tried the answers in [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers), that @chili555 suggested but none of them worked. I tried everything, installed both the package in the list, and the one for after September 2016... I still can't find my WiFi network in the list...

Comment: Perhaps your wireless device lacks a driver. Let's start by identifying the device. Please open a terminal and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Then edit your question to add the result.

Comment: @chili555 I edited my question to show the results

Comment: Please [run the network diagnostics](//askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and [edit] your question to include a link to the result. I'm voting to reopen but we need more information.

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me sometimes... It works for me when I do the following

1) Click on your wifi sign at the top right.
2) Click "Connect to hidden network".
3) Enter your network name.
4) Choose the type of wifi security you have set up (Most probably WPA & WPA2 Personal)
5)Enter your password

:)

Comment: no it did not work. I've tried this before, but I tried it again now and I correctly entered all the information, it just doesn't work